# How to render a form of another class view in Yii?

Tags: php, templates, yii

In Yii, I have a view belonging to class A, and in a view corresponding to this class, I want to add a form to create a model of another class.

So, in `protected/views/pictures/myview.php`, I have:

```
<?php
/* @var $this PicturesController */
/* @var $model Pictures */

$objectForm = new Objects();
$newForm = ObjectsController::renderPartial('create',array('model'=>$objectForm),true);

?>
```

And I am trying to add a form to render `protected/views/objects/create.php`. But the above code doesn't work since the view is still trying to load the create form from the Pictures class. Since I am obtaining errors saying that same properties of Objects are not defined, because the system is loading the Pictures create form.

How can I add the create form of the Objects model?

Note: I added "applications.controllers.*" to the import array in main.php, but I understand this is a bad practice. Is there any possible solutions that doesn't involve me to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you just needed to link the correct view in the renderPartial:

```
$objectForm = new Objects();
$newForm = ObjectsController::renderPartial('/objects/create',array('model'=>$objectForm),true); // "/objects/create", and not "create".
```

Those errors were giving because Yii understood you were rendering to the create view of pictures, and you gave it the model of Objects (rather than the model of Pictures).

If we were talking about a render call in the controller, and you want to render a view from another action that belongs to another controller, you do not render to this view directly. You have to "redirect" to the action of this other controller (that belongs to the other class).

Answer (score 0):

try like this this

```
$this->renderPartial('application.staff.views.default.create',array());
```

this is the format

```
$this->renderPartial('context_text.views.display._display_text');
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work because the form is trying to acces fields from the calling controller and not from the controller which I am trying to call